# if relationship exist then make another relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to apply something similar to if statement in other languages so that if a relationship exist then make another relationship.

I show my idea with a simple example: Suppose we have nodes as people and `marriedto` and `parentof` as relations:

```
// Nodes and relationships
CREATE (Homer:Person {name:'Homer', gender:'m'})
CREATE (Marge:Person {name:'Marge', gender:'f'})
CREATE (Bart:Person {name:'Bart', gender:'m'})
CREATE
    (Homer)-[:Parentof]->(Bart),
    (Homer)-[:Marriedto]->(Marge)
```

[image]

Now what I want to do is to check if any father relationship exist, then apply `Parentof` relation to mother too.

```
// Pseudo code:
//If (Father)-[:Parentof]->(Child) And (Father)-[:Married]->(Mother) Then (Mother)-[:Parentof]->(Child)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
MATCH (mother)-[:Marriedto]-(father)-[:Parentof]->(child)
MERGE (mother)-[r:Parentof]->(child)
RETURN r
```

You can use `CREATE` instead of `MERGE` if you know the relationship won't already exist.

Comment: Tnx 4 answer. Did u try it yourself? it doesn't make any changes for me.

Comment: @Woeitg in your question you have Bart as Homer's parent - I'm assuming this is a mistake? If not you can just remove the arrow (`>`) from the `(father)-[:Parentof]->(child)` relationship to match the pattern correctly.

Comment: Looks okay to me (except for the arrows on the images)